# How to add a double type value to a JTable row?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, netbeans-8

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     
{                                         
    try {

        Connection c = DBconnection.conn();
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * from menu where items=?");
        ps.setString(1, (String) jComboBox2.getSelectedItem());
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();           
        DefaultTableModel tbn = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

        Vector v = new Vector<>();
        v.add(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem());
       v.add(qty.getText());
```

**After this line i need to add price which is type double,I'm fetching it from database.And I need to know how to do it.Please someone help**

```
        tbn.addRow(v);
```

**Here I'm calculating total.**
            double total=0;

```
        for(int i=0; i<jTable1.getRowCount(); i++)
        {
            double amount = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 2)));
            jTable1.getValueAt(i,1));
            total+=amount;
        }
        Ltot.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(pos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}                         *emphasized text*
```

Answer (score 1):

[Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) should let you add the double easily:

```
v.add(price);
```

`double` is a *primitive type*, and you can't add those to `Vector`s, but Java has an object type corresponding to each primitive, and so it converts `price` into an instance of `Double` on the spot, and adds that instance to your `Vector`.

Quick sidenote: this means, among other things, that you'll pay a small price in heap space because of the new object you've created, so be a bit mindful of this if you do it a lot.

Also: `DefaultTableModel` is very no-frills as `TableModel`s go. But it can be very easy to prototype in. When you have some spare time, and if you need to improve on this code, I encourage you to look for implementations of `TableModel` that you'll find more suitable in various ways, such as letting you pull values out of an existing data structure instead of putting them into brand new `Vector`s. A good next step, for example, is to write your own implementation of `TableModel` for this specific table.